# Docker: bash: bundle: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I am trying to Dockerize my Rails 6 app but seem to be falling at the last hurdle. When running `docker-compose up` everything runs fine until i get to "Attaching to rdd-ruby_db_1, rdd-ruby_web_1" in the console and then I get the error `bash: bundle: command not found`.

I am aware of the other answers on Stackoverflow for the same issue but i have tried all before posting this.

**My Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ruby:2.7
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN cd /usr/bin/
RUN bundle install
FROM node:6.7.0
RUN npm install -g yarn
COPY . /myapp

# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts.
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the main process.
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

**My docker-compose**

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: xxx
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

I originally followed the guide in the Docker documentation thinking this would work over at https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/

Thanks.

Comment: Can you confirm that the `bundler` gem is installed in the docker image? For instance, have you tried to run `RUN gem install bundler` before the `RUN bundle install`?

Comment: Yeah i've put `RUN gem install bundler` before `RUN bundle install` but still gives me the same issue.

Comment: And the command `RUN gem install bundler` have succeeded? Maybe you need to configure the `PATH` environment variable so that it can find the `bundle` executable file? Can you `ssh` into the container and debug the commands like `which ruby`, `which gem` and `which bundle`?

Comment: I can't SSH in to it unless the container is running, which it isn't as it complains about the bundle. Unless i can configure the path in my docker file?

Comment: Actually using DockStation is says the path is `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

Comment: I has the same issue, docker run the entrypoint correctly but if I run "docker exec -if <image> /bin/bash" and in bash run "bundle" return to me bundle: command not found. Can you solve this?